# Delete files with a specific name from all folders available in my public_html folder

Tags: php, file-handling

I have a malicious file spread all around in my servers root directory and its folders. Is there any method/php script using which I can delete all of em at once from all folders.

Comment: What kind of name? Is it an exact file name?

Comment: What you really need to find out is what caused it in the first place. You have a security hole somewhere and that could be anything.

Comment: @Djanym Yea its an exact file name.

Comment: Hackers are quite smart (I didn't say intelligent). They're going to come back with another file name. Again; you need to find out where that security hole is that they breached. This could have been done either through the server and figured out the password or a backdoor somewhere, and/or a script you have that is used on your server that contains a security hole. Your question lacks detail here.

Comment: I already cleaned my server for backdoors. Those files are blank now. I just want to remove them to clean my server...

Comment: @ÁNjaneeShukla Ok. Btw, please ping back, I may not be in the question later on. One thing you need to do is to change the server's passwords and use a form of passphrase. I too had a hacker come in and uploaded a few files in one of the servers I take care of. I then changed the passwords to something much more secure and almost unguessable and it didn't happen again. If this was hit by "Anonymous", then you have some serious problems.

Answer (score 2):

```
function deleteFileFromDir($dir, $filename){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);

    unset($ffs[array_search('.', $ffs, true)]);
    unset($ffs[array_search('..', $ffs, true)]);

    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)){
            deleteFileFromDir($dir.'/'.$ff, $filename);
        } else {
            if( $ff == $filename ){
                echo "found ".$dir.'/'.$ff.'<br>';
                unlink($dir.'/'.$ff);
            }
        }
    }
}

$search_dir_path = '.'; // The same folder as the file location
$search_file = 'some_file_to_delete.txt';
deleteFileFromDir($search_dir_path, $search_file);
```

Just change `$search_dir_path` and `$search_file` variables as needed.

Answer (score -1):

Just replace **home/public_html/** and ***.txt** with correct address and name:

```
$objects = scandir(home/public_html/);
foreach ($objects as $object) {
  array_map('unlink', glob("*.txt"));
}
```

Comment: Tried but I think something is not working as expected. here is what I am using


<?php
$objects = scandir('home/aamedias/public_html/');
foreach ($objects as $object) {
  array_map('unlink', glob("405.php"));
}
?>

Comment: That isn't my downvote here, but this would only (probably) work (better) if it's set on a cronjob. However, and as I said [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53660705/delete-files-with-a-specific-name-from-all-folders-available-in-my-public-html-f#comment94180307_53660705), they're just going to outfox the fox, as it were.

Comment: @ÁNjaneeShukla You can not run code from subfolders, You should use Cron Jobs over sudo or edit httpd.conf.